# Problem creating static/dynamic c++ libraries in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, build

When I try to build my c++ library (in both static and dynamic mode) using visual studio 2008, in the debug folder, instead of .lib or .dll file, some .obj files are created along with an .idb and an .pdb file.
how can I make visual studio build the library file?

Comment: Did you try a dir /s to find it?  I think there is more than one "debug" folder in the project tree...

Answer (score 1):

You're either looking in the wrong place or there's a problem in your build.

Open the `BuildLog.htm` file that VS creates when it does a build (there should be a link you can click in the Build Output window).  It'll tell you where it's putting the file. Look for the line containing an "/OUT:" option.

Comment: Do tell what the problem was - others may benefit from your experience.

Comment: The problem: I wanted to build a downloaded project which had a pre-configured build directory, and I searched the default build directory and could not find them.